# Modified Taylor diagrams

Tags: python, machine-learning, matplotlib

There is a type of diagram summarizing how well predictions from numerical models fit expectations; one obvious use case is comparing machine-learning regression models. Modified Taylor diagrams are described in [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2014RS005435/abstract).

I'd like to know if [my implementation](https://bitbucket.org/lbillingham/modifiedtaylordiagrams/src) follows best practices for using matplotlib, and how I might incorporate better testing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as fa
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder as gf

class TaylorDiagramPoint(object):
  """
  A single point on a Modified Taylor Diagram.
  How well do the values predicted match the values expected

      * do the means match
      * do the standard deviations match
      * are they correlated
      * what is the normalized error standard deviation
      * what is the bias?

  Notation:

      * s_ := sample standard deviation 
      * m_ := sample mean 
      * nesd := normalized error standard deviation;
                > nesd**2 = s_predicted**2 + s_expected**2 -
                            2 * s_predicted * s_expected * corcoeff
  """
  def __init__(self, expected, predicted, pred_name, point_id):

    self.pred = predicted
    self.expd = expected
    self.s_pred = np.std(self.pred)
    self.s_expd = np.std(self.expd)
    self.s_normd = self.s_pred / self.s_expd 
    self.bias = (np.mean(self.pred) - np.mean(self.expd)) / self.s_expd 
    self.corrcoef = np.corrcoef(self.pred, self.expd)[0, 1]
    self.corrcoef = min([self.corrcoef, 1.0])
    self.nesd = np.sqrt(self.s_pred**2 + self.s_expd**2 - 
                   2 * self.s_pred * self.s_expd * self.corrcoef)
    self.name = pred_name
    self.point_id = point_id              

class ModTaylorDiagram(object):
  """
    Given predictions and expected numerical data 
    plot the standard deviation of the differences and correlation between
    expected and predicted in a single-quadrant polar plot, with
    r=stddev and theta=arccos(correlation).
  """
  def __init__(self, fig=None, label='expected'):
    """
    Set up Taylor diagram axes. 
    """   

    self.title_polar = r'Correlation'
    self.title_xy = r'Normalized Standard Deviation'    
    self.title_expected = r'Expected'
    self.max_normed_std = 1.55 
    self.s_min = 0


    # Correlation labels
    corln_r = np.append(np.linspace(0.0, 0.9, 10), 0.95)
    corln_ang = np.arccos(corln_r)      # Conversion to polar angles
    grid_loc1 = gf.FixedLocator(corln_ang)    # Positions
    tick_fmttr1 = gf.DictFormatter(dict(zip(corln_ang, map(str, corln_r))))

    # Normalized standard deviation axis
    tr = PolarAxes.PolarTransform()
    grid_helper = fa.GridHelperCurveLinear(tr,
                                  extremes=(0, np.pi/2, # 1st quadrant
                                            self.s_min, self.max_normed_std),
                                  grid_locator1=grid_loc1,
                                  tick_formatter1=tick_fmttr1)
    self.fig = fig                                   
    if self.fig is None:
      self.fig = plt.figure()

    # setup axes
    ax = fa.FloatingSubplot(self.fig, 111, grid_helper=grid_helper)
    # make the axis (polar ax child used for plotting)    
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(ax)
    # hide base-axis labels etc   
    self.ax.axis['bottom'].set_visible(False)  
    self._setup_axes()

    # attach the ploar axes
    self.polar_ax = self.ax.get_aux_axes(tr)    

    # Add norm error stddev and nesd==1 contours
    self._plot_req1_cont(label)
    self._plot_nesd_cont(levels=np.arange(0.0, 1.75, 0.25))
    self.points = []


  def add_prediction(self, expected, predicted, predictor_name, 
                     plot_pt_id):
    """
    Add a prediction/model to the diagram
    """
    this_point = TaylorDiagramPoint(expected, predicted, 
                                    predictor_name, plot_pt_id)   
    self.points.append(this_point)

  def plot(self):
    """
    Place all the loaded points onto the figure 
    """
    rs = []
    thetas = []
    biases = []
    names = []
    point_tags = []
    for point in self.points:
      rs.append(point.s_expd)
      thetas.append(np.arccos(point.corrcoef))
      biases.append(point.bias)
      names.append(point.name)
      point_tags.append(point.point_id)

    sc = self.polar_ax.scatter(thetas, rs, c=biases, 
                               s=35, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    for i, tag in enumerate(point_tags):                         
      self.polar_ax.text(thetas[i], rs[i], tag,
                         horizontalalignment='center',
                         verticalalignment='bottom')

    self.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)                         
    cbaxes = self.fig.add_axes([0.238, 0.9, 0.55, 0.03])
    cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, cax=cbaxes, orientation='horizontal',
                        format='%.2f')
    cbaxes.set_xlabel('Normalized bias')
    cbaxes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    cbaxes.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
    self.show_key()

  def show_key(self):
    """
    add annotation key for model IDs and normalization factors
    """
    textstr = ''
    for i, p in enumerate(self.points):
      if i > 0:
        textstr += '\n'

      textstr += r'{0}$\rightarrow${1}: std/{2:.3f}'.format(p.point_id,
                                                      p.name, p.s_expd)                        
    props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', alpha=0.75)
    # place a text box in upper left in axes coords
    self.ax.text(0.75, 0.98, textstr, transform=self.ax.transAxes, fontsize=11,
        verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)


  def show_norm_factor(self):
    """
    add annotation about the normalization factor
    """        
    n_fact = self.points[0]
    out_str = r'Norm Factor {:.2f}'.format(n_fact)   
    x = 0.95 * self.max_normed_std   
    y = 0.95 * self.max_normed_std             
    self.ax.text(x, y, 
                 out_str,
                 horizontalalignment='right',
                 verticalalignment='top', 
                 bbox={'edgecolor': 'black', 'facecolor':'None'})      

  def _plot_req1_cont(self, label):
    """
    plot the normalized standard deviation = 1 contour and label
    """
    my_purple = [0.414, 0.254, 0.609]
    t = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2)
    r = np.ones_like(t)
    self.polar_ax.plot(t, r, '--', color=my_purple, label=label)  
    self.polar_ax.text(0, 1, 
                       self.title_expected, 
                       color=my_purple, 
                       horizontalalignment='center',
                       verticalalignment='center')


  def _plot_nesd_cont(self, levels=6):
    """
    plot the normalized error standard deviation contours
    """
    my_blue = [0.171875, 0.39453125, 0.63671875]
    rs, ts = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(self.s_min, self.max_normed_std),
                         np.linspace(0, np.pi/2))

    nesd = np.sqrt(1.0 + rs**2 - 2 * rs * np.cos(ts))
    contours = self.polar_ax.contour(ts, rs, nesd, levels, 
                                     colors=my_blue, linestyles='dotted')

    self.polar_ax.clabel(contours, inline=1, fontsize=10)

  def _setup_angle_axis(self):
    """
    set the ticks labels etc for the angle axis
    """
    loc = 'top'
    self.ax.axis[loc].set_axis_direction('bottom')  
    self.ax.axis[loc].toggle(ticklabels=True, label=True)
    self.ax.axis[loc].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction('top')
    self.ax.axis[loc].label.set_axis_direction('top')        
    self.ax.axis[loc].label.set_text(self.title_polar)

  def _setup_x_axis(self):
    """
    set the ticks labels etc for the x axis
    """
    loc = 'left'
    self.ax.axis[loc].set_axis_direction('bottom') 
    self.ax.axis[loc].label.set_text(self.title_xy)     


  def _setup_y_axis(self):
    """
    set the ticks labels etc for the y axis
    """
    loc = 'right'
    self.ax.axis[loc].set_axis_direction('top')   
    self.ax.axis[loc].toggle(ticklabels=True)
    self.ax.axis[loc].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction('left')      
    self.ax.axis[loc].label.set_text(self.title_xy)  

  def _setup_axes(self):
    """
    set the ticks labels etc for the angle x and y axes
    """
    self._setup_angle_axis()
    self._setup_x_axis()
    self._setup_y_axis()


if '__main__'== __name__:
  mtd = ModTaylorDiagram()
  x = np.linspace(0.0, 4.0*np.pi, 100)
  observed = np.sin(x)
  # Models
  pred_0 = observed + 0.2*np.random.randn(len(x))     
  pred_1 = 0.8*observed + 2*np.random.randn(len(x)) 
  pred_2 = np.sin(x - np.pi/10)  - 0.5*np.random.randn(len(x))        
  mods = [pred_0, pred_1, pred_2]         
  mod_names = [r'Model 0', r'Model 1', r'Model 2']
  mod_ids = [r'a', r'$\beta$', r'$\spadesuit$']


  for i, model in enumerate(mods):
    mtd.add_prediction(observed, model, mod_names[i], mod_ids[i])

  mtd.plot()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious remarks about whitespace:

Whitespace is important in Python. You got trailing whitespaces all over the place and you use an indentation of 2 spaces where 4 is prescribed by the [official PEP8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). When talking about sticking to best practices in Python, starting with PEP8 is a good idea. There's a lot more violations going on, a couple of them can be checked using [the off-line tool](http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) and/or [the on-line tool](http://pep8online.com).

I like how you split your functions. It's straightforward and maintainable, except the large amount of magic numbers. I have a personal dislike for numerals in function names and variables (for example: `grid_locator1`) and constructs like the following make me think you got naming problems:

```
grid_locator1=grid_loc1,
tick_formatter1=tick_fmttr1
```

Basically, you got the usage of `matplotlib` down quite nicely. The rest could use some work.